# Hazelcast WARNING with exception

Tags: hazelcast

Hi I am getting this exception in my member logs.What might be the reason for this exception?

```
2018-04-17 15:38:59.734 - WARN --- [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    : [172.16.42.193]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Connection[id=30, /172.16.42.193:5701->/172.16.15.16:54266, endpoint=[172.16.15.16]:5701, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=30, /172.16.42.193:5701->/172.16.15.16:54266, endpoint=[172.16.15.16]:5701, alive=true, type=MEMBER], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.AbstractChannel.read(AbstractChannel.java:94)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioChannelReader.handle(NioChannelReader.java:127)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.handleSelectionKey(NioThread.java:401)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.handleSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:386)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Connection reset by peer` message essentially means connection was closed by the other side, which is the other member `[172.16.15.16]:5701` in this case. What do you see in the logs of the other member?

It might be due to a forced shutdown or an ungraceful shutdown on the other side, or a network error.